# What's the meaning of flowBuilder.methodCallNode.parameters method in a flow definition?

Tags: jsf-2.2

Can anyone show me a simple example using both *expression* and *parameters* methods of *javax.​faces.​flow.​builder.MethodCallBuilder* class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this:

```
String first = "first";

flowBuilder.methodCallNode("nodeName").expression("#{" myBeanName.myMethod('" + first + "', false, false)}");
```

Signature if my method is:

```
public String myMethod(String first, boolean flag1, boolean flag2)
```

myMethod should return name of view node or return node where you want to go next.

I do not use *parameters* explicitly.

Comment: ...for my node definition:
"#{myBean.myMethod(anotherBean.oneValue)}". But my doubt is about how to call 'parameters' method however. Thanks.